# fluentvalidtion client-side error message for Length do not show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I used FluentValidation to verify the LoginViewModel, like this

```
public class LoginViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(l => l.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("非空").Length(5, 100);
            RuleFor(l => l.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(5, 100).WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' 必须是 {MaxLength} 个字符，您已经输入了 {TotalLength} 字符。");
            RuleFor(l => l.Code).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(4);
        }
    }
```

when I input too long or too short into the password,I got error message is in jquery.validate :

> Please enter a value between 5 and 100 characters long.

I think this should show the default error message for FluentValidation.
The error message for the username with WithMessage like this

> '用户名' 必须是 100 个字符，您已经输入了 {TotalLength} 字符。

{TotalLength} showed up

MaximumLength and MinimumLength They all have the same problem.
others work fine

```
Golbal.cs:

protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
        }
```

All of the error messages I have said are Before submitting，Js verification result。

Answer (score 0):

I could not reshow your issue, could you please provide a simple project for it.

It was working on my solution.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotNull().Length(5, 20).
            WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' 必须是 {MaxLength} 个字符，您已经输入了 {TotalLength} 字符。");
    }
}



    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var customer = new Customer
        {
            Surname = "韩非子"
        };
        CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
        var results = validator.Validate(customer);

        return View();
    }
}
```

You should saw the result as below picture.

[Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXTcM.png)

Comment: All of the error messages I have said are Before submitting。I put a simple project on github：https://github.com/FQLin/FluentValidationSimple